# Divide model in fixed lenght pieces

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

in order to print it, i have to divide this model in 3 parts, each precisely 28cm long, how can i do it?

[image: here is the model]

I tried using the mesure tool, but I wasn't able to obtain precise mesures and to snap thing to it.

thanks

Comment: knife project, using some edges spaced by 28cm